# How to reset msconfig

Tags: startup

My friend told me that when he changed his msconfig cores from 1 to 2 his laptop performance increased. So I changed it from 1 to 2 the clickled apply without restarting my pc. Then I regretted it and switched back to one core without restarting. Now I'm standing here with my BIOS open because qhen I start up my pc it doesn't matter if I pick start windows normally it always redirects me to launch startup repair which does nothing. I have an Optiplex 760.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Windows key + X key. And select Run.
2. Type msconfig in the Run box and hit Enter.
3. On the Services tab of the System Configuration dialog box, tap or click to select the Hide all Microsoft services check box, and
   then tap or click Enable all.
4. On the Startup tab of the System Configuration dialog box, tap or click Open Task Manager.
5. On the Startup tab in Task Manager, for each startup item, select the item and then click Enable.
6. Close Task Manager.
7. On the Startup tab of the System Configuration dialog box, tap or click OK, and then restart the computer.

Comment: I can't start up my pc.